# Toggle/Checkbox within a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I have a toggle from bootstraptoggle.com and I put it inside a button. It works in Chrome, but not Firefox. How can I have it where when you click the button it forces the toggle or check box to check and on check when the button is pressed. I need a jquery function that checks and unchecks after each each other click.

JSP:

```
    <button id="topology_button" type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default">Portfolio
                                <input type="checkbox" class="expander" id="toggle"
                                    data-on="Portfolio" data-off="Topology" checked
                                    data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">
                            Topology
                        </button>
```

Here is the Jquery, I'd add it. So every odd click will uncheck the box/toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggle').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
        $('#project-list-area').fadeIn('slow'),
        $('#topology').fadeOut('slow');
    else
        $('#topology').fadeIn('slow'),
        $('#project-list-area').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: Putting input elements inside button elements is kind of weird in general. Isn't there a better way to implement whatever this is supposed to represent? (By the way, Java != JavaScript.)

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Change the toggle on the click event of the button. Also that's just normal HTML for our concern, the Java/JSP tag isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#toggle').change(function() {

    if (this.checked)
{

        $('#project-list-area').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#topology').fadeOut('slow');
}
    else
{

        $('#topology').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#project-list-area').fadeOut('slow');
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="topology_button" type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default">Portfolio
                                <input type="checkbox" class="expander" id="toggle"
                                    data-on="Portfolio" data-off="Topology" checked
                                    data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">
                            Topology
                        </button>

<div id='project-list-area'>
project-list-area
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Semi colons instead of commas at the end of the first line in the if and else